# Topological Definition of Continuous in Coq

Tags: coq, topology

So I'm really new to coq, functional programming altogether, and I'm trying to express the topological definition of continuity in coq. I'm using this
[code](https://gist.github.com/andrejbauer/d31e9666d5f950dd8ccd) to define a topology in coq. My best attempt at expressing continuity given a particular function is,

```
    Definition Continuous (X:Type)(TX:Topology X)(Y:Type)(TY:Topology Y)(f:X->Y):=
        forall V, exists U, all y:V, some x:U, f x = y.
```

I'm getting the error

> "The term "f x" has type "Y" while it is expected to have type
>    "Prop".

No idea what to do, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Coq's parser was interpreting `y` wrong. I was able to fix the problem by changing the notation for `all` and `some` a little bit:

```
Notation "'all' x 'in' U , P" := (forall x, U x -> P) (at level 200).
Notation "'some' x 'in' U , P" := (exists x, U x /\ P) (at level 200).

Definition continuous (X:Type)(TX:topology X)(Y:Type)(TY:topology Y)(f:X->Y):=
  forall V, exists U, all y in V, some x in U, f x = y.
```

Notice how the notation levels are different and how it uses the `in` keyword instead of `:`. I don't know if there's a way of getting `:` to work; Coq 8.5 kept complaining if I tried to.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much.